# Submit a job with MyBatis passing a struct as parameter to the called procedure

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, mybatis, jobs

I'm using MyBatis to execute queries for my java project.

I have to call a package procedure, and right now I'm doing it this way:

```
{
    call MY_PACKAGE.very_long_procedure(
        #{in_custom_type, mode=IN, jdbcType=STRUCT, jdbcTypeName=CUSTOM_TYPE}
    )
}
```

Where `CUSTOM_TYPE` is defined as follows:

```
create or replace type tp_calcolo as object (
    id_type              NUMBER(38,0)
    name_tt              VARCHAR2(200 CHAR)
);
```

I'm able to call it, and it works.

It gets called by clicking on a button. The problem is that it takes a lot of time to end, and my server's timeout is set to 120 seconds, so after 2 minutes I get an exception due to request timeout.

What I want to do is change my procedure call to a job creation, so that it gets executed as a thread and the request gets done right after the job creation.

This is how I should create the job:

```
DECLARE
  X NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SYS.DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT
    (
      job        => X
     ,what       => 'DECLARE 
  in_custom_type    CUSTOM_TYPE
BEGIN

  in_custom_type := ?; --what to write here? how to insert custom type?

  MY_PACKAGE.very_long_procedure(
    in_custom_type
  ) 
  COMMIT; 
END;'
     ,next_date  => to_date('07/15/2014 11.37.08','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
     ,no_parse   => FALSE
    );
:JobNumber := to_char(X);
END;
```

Now, it works fine if I replace the `?` with `custom_type('12', 'PACKAGE CALL')`
, as I'm creating a new object. But what if the object is passed as struct to MyBatis?

How would I pass it to the job?

p.s. Yes, I could simply change settings for the server's timeout, but I can't, as the server is not mine and I can't directly configure it.

Comment: You can wrap the code in a function and call MyBatis?

Comment: @Polppan You mean creating a function on the schema which creates the job, and call that function from MyBatis? Unfortunately no, I can't

Comment: So you can only access already created procedure from MyBatis?

Comment: @Polppan Yes, it's the only thing I can do :/